# Still problem with 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, int, iterable

thanks for your hints, I have the following code in python3 and I keep having the same error "int" is not iterable, would you know what is the problem?

```
formatRequiredNewH={(101, 1): [2, 3], (102, 3): [3], (103, 2): [2], (104, 3): [1], (105, 2): [777]}

fixedUniqueCompilation=[1,2,3,4,5]

try:
    for actClass in list(formatRequiredNewH.keys()):        
        for h in fixedUniqueCompilation:
            print(formatRequiredNewH[actClass])
            if 2 in formatRequiredNewH[actClass][0]:
                print("Works?")
except:
    print("not")
```

Comment: `formatRequiredNewH[actClass][0]` is an integer. Do you mean just `formatRequiredNewH[actClass]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if 2 == formatRequiredNewH[actClass][0]:
    etc..
```

**in** means for python that it should be looking at an iterable. ;)

Unless you are looking for 2 in 102 for example and then you need to cast from int to string :

```
if '2' in str(formatRequiredNewH[actClass][0]):
```